# javascript onclick fade div in (short code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, fade

i'm been lookin all over the place and cannot find exactly what im after anywhere.

the html structure is basically.

```
<ul> 
   <li><a href="">link</a></li>
   <div id="us">hidden info</div>
</ul>
```

the css structure is.

```
#us {display:none}
```

I'd like it so when "link" is clicked the div "us" is changed from dipslay:none; to display:block, in a graceful fade in as little lines of code as possible, and then again when the link is clicked its toggled back to display:hidden.

I'm aware that there are lots of things that can do this, but im really lookin for that simplicity in code.

thanks for your time x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with a duration (works in all jQuery versions), like this:

```
$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });
```

Or, if you're on jQuery 1.4.4+, use [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) like this:

```
$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").fadeToggle(); });
```

Note though, a `<div>` isn't a valid child of  `<ul>`, so it may render unexpectedly in several browsers...it'd be better to use proper markup.

Comment: @AndreKR - yup, added by [Paul Irish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89484/paul-irish) iirc :)

Comment: thanks for this, i've tried to use this one as well as the others, but having problems with isolating it to just that 1 div.

when i click to toggle #us it also toggles #twitter and #contact even though they've all setup with their own ids.

Comment: @Owen - IDs should be unique, do you have `id="us"` multiple times in the page?

Comment: nope, each one has its own id (so yes they are unique) but its still toggling each one :s very strange

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#contact").toggle("fast"); }); 
$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });});

Comment: @Owen - You're attaching a click handler to every `<a>` (each time) for every `<div>`, you need to more uniquely identify the `<a>`, or better:*relatively* find the `<div>`...it shouldn't be in the `<ul>` directly, so where is it in relation to the `<a>`?

Comment: erm, to many words there. the structure is, body -> #left -> .navigation ul -> li -> a (this is the link) -> div(to open with unique id)

Comment: @Owen - The div is inside the `<a>`, or beside it as a sibling?

Comment: its outside. li a /a /li div content /div

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zmirY15g <- the doc if thats any help. excuse the poor code ha, i'll clean it up a lot later

Comment: @Owen - As I said in comments and the answer, that isn't valid HTML, you can't have a `<div>` there, can you move it inside the `<li>`, after the `<a>`, or in it's own `<li>`?

Comment: yup, done, its now <li><a> link </a></li><li id="us>content</li>

Comment: @Owen - Ok so now you don't even need IDs, you can just do this once: `$("ul li a").click(function() { $(this).parent().next().toggle("fast"); });`, that same click handler will work for all anchors, it'll get the next `<li>` to toggle relative to itself.

Comment: ah this is working next to flawless. i can figure out how to ignore non-expanding links, thank you ever so much nick, very much appreciated :)

Comment: @Owen - Any chance you can give those `<li>` or `<a>` elements that do the expanding a class?

Comment: its all good, none of the menus are empty anymore so it all worked out, is it easy enough to make it so if a new menu is opened any current open elements get closed?

Comment: posted :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319809/jquery-toggle-menu-hide-show-close-other-menus-when-new-menu-opens

and yup, ive accepted the answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("#idfortheanchor").bind("click", function() {
    if ($("#us").is(":visible")) {
        $("#us").hide();
    } else {
        $("#us").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no fade-toggle in the jQuery core, I'd use:

```
$('a').toggle(
    function() { $('#us').fadeIn(); },
    function() { $('#us').fadeOut(); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery UI is an option for you, I can only recommend it.
jQuery UI extends jQuery with many nice effects:

```
show( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

But check out the website itself: http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

Comment: Yeah, but look at all the nice effects! :-)

Answer (score 0):

thank you everybody for your input! You've been very helpful! The final snippet I've used which i deemed most appropriate was from Nick.

```
$("ul li a").click(function() { $(this).parent().next().toggle("fast"); });
```

so thanks again everybody! and hope someone else can find this useful! x