# jQuery toggle menu hide/show (close other menus when new menu opens)

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, show-hide

thanks to [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) I've got a nice toggle menu going, however i've come up with the problem that if users keep clicking new menus the page will keep growing which i dont want, so the idea is:

as one menu opens, any currently open menus to close.

The full source is @ http://the-dot.co.uk/new/

here are 2 snippets of the code I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li a").click(function() { $(this).parent().next().toggle("fast"); });
});
</script>
```

and html structure is

```
 <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a name="us" title="us">Us</a></li>
    <li id="us">about thedot</li>
    <li><a name="portfolio" title="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a name="contact" title="contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="contact">contact deets
    </li>
    <li><a name="twitter" title="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li id="twit">some twitter shit</li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
```

thanks.

Comment: the 1st n 2nd paragraph explains the problem and what i want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul li a").click(function() { 
      $(this).parent().next().toggle("fast").siblings("[id]").hide("fast");
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K6TSv/), what this does it toggle the sibling `<li>` still, but then looks at *its* [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) that have an ID attribute and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) them if show.

---

If the markup isn't locked in, you could simplify it further like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="toggle">Us</li>
    <li class="content">about thedot</li>
    <li class="toggle">Portfolio</li>
    <li class="content"></li>
    <li class="toggle">Contact</li>
    <li class="content">contact deets</li>
    <li class="toggle">Twitter</li>
    <li class="content">some twitter shit</li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

And script like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("li.content").hide();
  $("ul.navigation").delegate("li.toggle", "click", function() { 
      $(this).next().toggle("fast").siblings(".content").hide("fast");
  });
});
```

It's a matter of preference, but I find this approach a bit cleaner and more style-able, [check out the result here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K6TSv/1/).

Comment: Ah, genius :) the 1st bit of code works perfectly. I've actually got a lot of php and other stuff going on in the menus, so its more of a reveal section than menu. and i found when i re-wrote it to fit in the 2nd alternative which is a lot tidier that it messed with alot of the other styles. so thanks but i'll use your first answer :) THANK YOU EVER SO MUCH :)